# Laravel eloquent models - filter by sum

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I have two models:

User: id, name, email

Commission: id, user_id, amount, paid, refund, created_at

Relationship: User hasMany Commission

I need to calculate the sum of commisions per user per month and download  it in a CSV file for mass payment, but these sums must be greater than  25 and smaller than 25000.

Currently here is what I have, but how can I filter based on the Amount range? I need to mark as paid those Commissions, which has been paid, but only those will be paid, which are greater than 25 and smaller than 25000

```
$commissions = Commissions::whereYear('created_at', $date->year)
->whereMonth('created_at', $date->month)
->where('paid', 'no')
->where('refund', 'no')
->get();
```

I could filter by calculating the amount within a foreach, but I'm almost sure there is a much more elegant way in Laravel to do this.

Comment: $commissions = $user->commissions()->whereYear('created_at', $date->year)->whereMonth('created_at', $date->month)->where('paid', 'no')->where('refund', 'no')->sum('your field name');

Comment: I know the sum method, but how will this filter by range?

Comment: Actually, the query is not for just one user, but for commissions in general for that month.

Comment: then you have to print you user name , then use foreach loop

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: The sums per user have to be between 25 and 25000?

Comment: Yes, the sum per user per month

Comment: So you want a list of the month's commissions that excludes users with `sum ≤ 25`? And per user only includes so many commissions that `sum < 25000`?

Comment: Yes, exactly thats what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a simple solution:

```
$commissions = Commission::whereYear('created_at', $date->year)
    ->whereMonth('created_at', $date->month)
    ->where('paid', 'no')
    ->where('refund', 'no')
    ->where('amount', '<', 25000)
    ->orderByDesc('amount')
    ->get();
$grouped = $commissions->groupBy('user_id');
$grouped = $grouped->filter(function($commissions) {
    return $commissions->sum('amount') > 25;
});
$grouped = $grouped->map(function($commissions) {
    $sum = 0;
    return $commissions->filter(function($commission) use(&$sum) {
        $sum += $commission->amount;
        return $sum < 25000;
    });
});
$commissions = $grouped->collapse();
```

Comment: Finally, I was able to manage the issue, with a foreach. Anyway, this was the most helpfull answer, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Easy just another condition with `whereBetween`

```
$commissions = $user->commissions()
    ->whereYear('created_at', $date->year)
    ->whereMonth('created_at', $date->month)
    ->where([['paid' , 'no'], ['refund', 'no']])
    ->whereBetween('price', [25, 25000])
    ->sum('price');
```

or:

```
$commissions = $user->commissions()
    ->whereYear('created_at', $date->year)
    ->whereMonth('created_at', $date->month)
    ->where([['paid' , 'no'], ['refund', 'no']])
    ->sum('price')->filter(function($value, $key){

        return in_array($value, [25,25000]);

     });
```

Comment: The wherebetween will not search in the sum of the comissions

Comment: @Zoli there easy again :)